# Deleting from localStorage: should I use delete or .removeItem?

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage

I'm using `localStorage` in a Chrome extension.

Is there any difference between `delete localStorage[key]` and `window.localStorage.removeItem(key)` or do they behave identically?

Note that I choose `window.localStorage.removeItem(key)` to correspond exactly to the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute), but `localStorage.removeItem(key)` is how it would probably look in the wild.

Comment: There's no need to specify window because this is a native JS function I pressume.

Comment: localStorage is a property of the window, not of JS. For example, an iframe will have its own local storage.

Put differently, localStorage is part of the HTML spec, not of the ES spec.

The reason you don't need to specify window is that it is the global object. The global object is part of the ES spec: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-global-object.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

There's no difference in Chrome, but i recommend using localStorage.removeItem(key) so that you get in the habit of doing so.  That way, when you go to use localStorage in a website, you are already using the method that is most likely to work with shims and polyfills for outdated browsers.

Comment: If you're looking for a prettier API for localStorage and sessionStorage, try this out:  https://github.com/nbubna/store