# Difference between removeItem and delete

Tags: javascript, local-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting from localStorage: should I use delete or .removeItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906494/deleting-from-localstorage-should-i-use-delete-or-removeitem)

What is the difference between

```
localStorage.removeItem("my_variable_in_storage")
```

And

```
delete(localStorage.my_variable_in_storage)
```

Besides that first returns "undefined" and second true boolean.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906494/deleting-from-localstorage-should-i-use-delete-or-removeitem

Comment: If you look at the spec for [delete](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.1) (and then [\[\[Delete\]\]](http://es5.github.com/#x8.12.7)), the algorithms make no mention of _Storage_ so you may find some browsers won't `delete` cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `localStorage.removeItem()`. While delete may work, it's not part of the spec and it may just be a lucky coincidence that it's working for you right now.