# keeping value of previous jquery global variable intact, even after onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript global variable does not persist when navigate to another page (which also uses same js file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139351/javascript-global-variable-does-not-persist-when-navigate-to-another-page-which)

I have a script

```
<script>

var pn=0;

function set()
{
pn=parseInt(pn)+1;
}
</script>
```

After the first execution of `set`, `pn` will be 1.

After the page is reloaded, `pn` retains its value of `1` so on the next execution of `set` it will be incremented to `2`.

How can I preserve global variables across page reloads?

Comment: Do you want to store this value across multiple users or per user?

Answer (score 3):

You could save the value of pn into a cookie via [jquery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). Set cookie:

```
$.cookie("pn", pn);
```

Get value from cookie:

```
$.cookie("pn");
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, you can't. There is no way to persist client side variables on a page reload.

I would suggest using either

[jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) (cookies)

or if your browsers supports HTML5:

[HTML5 web storage](http://caniuse.com/#search=namevalue-storage) (local-/session storage)

Comment: localStorage is better than cookies.. at least in my opinion... easier to use, too

Comment: @KatCox At long as the browser supports it, and the data is intented to be used on client-side only - yes :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use cookies, here is an example how you can achieve it:

```
var pn = 0;

function increment() {
  pn = parseInt(pn, 10) + 1;
  setCookie('pn', pn, 200);
  console.log(pn);
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays) {
  var exdate=new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
  document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
  var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
  for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {
    x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
    y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
    x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    if (x==c_name) {
      return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

(function () {
  pn = getCookie('pn') || 0;
}());
```

Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/ucitul/3

Answer (score 0):

You should store your value in a cookie, the querystring or the hashfragment and then get the value at the page load.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). It's rather simple and will solve your problem