# how to remove localstorage if you assign object instead of key?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that assigns object for a localStorage. How do i delete it after tab/window has been closed?

`localSotrage['data'] = JSON.stringify({folder1: {logedIn: 1}, folder2: {logedIn: 0}, folder3: {logedIn: 1}});`

i tried using

`delete window.localStorage['data']` and
`window.localStorage.removeItem(data)` and
`localStorage.removeItem(data)`

but not working. when i close the browser and access it again it's leading me to straight to the landing page. any help on how to do it? thanks a lot in advance

Comment: `localStore.removeItem("data")`

Comment: You can only replace contents in local storage; not delete it

Comment: @aliasm2k: Of course you can delete it.

Comment: The solutions you tried will work, though as @tymeJV pointed out, you forgot the quotes around `data` when using `.removeItem()`. If you're having an issue, it isn't demonstrated in the question.

Comment: and *"...if you assign object instead of key"* doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @cookiemonster thanks. what do you mean by it doesnt make sense if i assign object and not key? does it mean im not giving a localStorage something like a unique identity? please explain further. thanks again

Comment: @user2999165: A key is another word for a property of an object. It isn't a value that can be assigned, so I'm not sure what you were trying to explain there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this behavior i think you should use **sessionStorage**, but in this particular case i'll use:

`window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  delete localStorage['data'];
};`

To remove the value and its key, setting it to null will leave the key in place.

By the way you misspelled localStorage in your code, just letting you know =)

Comment: thanks for answering. i didnt use sessionStorage since i dont want to complicate with IOS browser. i will try your answer and let you know. and thanks a lot for noticing that. really my bad i didn't notice that. thanks again

Comment: You welcome, good luck with your project, the other users also gave good tips, specially user2864740 =)

Comment: thanks. i tried using `window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  delete localStorage['data'];
};` what happen is that when you access the folder you will see the landing page then when you refresh thats the only time it will redirect you to the login page. can you help me find out what im doing wrong here? thanks

Comment: Not sure if i understand, what is the behavior you are trying to achieve?, the code i gave you only removes that value from localStorage once you close the tab/window or refresh, or even go to another website, on those cases you will be deleting the value. If its not doing that, you might be setting that value again at some point, let me know what is that you are trying to achieve, if it is too diferent from the original question i guess you should open another one and mark one of these answers as the correct one for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove a specific item you have save in the localStorage you will do it like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value"); // Set a value with a "key"
localStorage.getItem("key"); // Get the value associated with "key"
localStorage.removeItem("key"); // Remove value associated with "key"
```

You could also clear all your localStorage. That is done in the following way:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Then you will clear all the data in the localStorange.

You are able to do the same with sessionStorage. The same methods are used.

Comment: One gotcha here though here is that if you had assigned `localStorage["clear"]` so just call `localStorage.removeItem("clear")` before calling `localStorage.clear()`

Comment: thanks guys for answering. amitab so if i have `localSotrage['data']` then i need to have `localStorage.removwItem("data")` then `localStorage.clear()`? i'll try it and let you know

Answer (score -1):

Just set the value to `null` or `undefined`:

```
localSotrage['data'] = null;
```

You can also use:

```
delete localStorage.data   //or 
localStorage.removeItem("data")
```

Comment: hi thanks for helping. i tried it both. but what happen is that when you access the folder you will see the landing page then when you refresh thats the only time it will redirect you to the login page. can you help me find out why this is happening? thanks

Comment: I appreciate it if the downvoter could comment and let me know what's wrong with the answer!

Answer (score -2):

The *correct* approach to dealing with Local Storage is to use the [Storage API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#storage-0), which includes the `setItem`, `getItem`, and `removeItem` methods - do this *instead* of direct property access. Using the API will work reliably across browsers (where such is supported) *and* over Local Storage shims.

(The following shows the API works; if there is an error, pay attention to *exactly* what it says.)

```
localStorage.clear();                // reset for examples

localStorage.setItem("data", "hi!")
localStorage.length                  // -> 1
localStorage.getItem("data")         // -> "hi!"

localStorage.setItem("data", null)   // set value to null
localStorage.length                  // -> 1 (key NOT removed!)
localStorage.getItem("data")         // -> null

localStorage.removeItem("data")      // remove key
localStorage.length                  // -> 0 (key really WAS removed!)
localStorage.getItem("data")         // -> null
```

Another reason to use the above API is `localStorage.setItem("getItem", "foo")` won't break the next usage of `localStorage.getItem` as the storage key/value pairs and storage *object* properties are kept clearly distinct.

---

In Chrome (and maybe elsewhere), the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator, which *removes properties* from normal JavaScript Objects, "works". I do *not* recommend or use this shorthand for various reasons.

1. It is not *not* discussed/defined by the W3C API at all
2. It confuses the JS properties and the underlying model; consider `localStorage['getItem']` and variants, as discussed above
3. It cannot and does not work over shims

Example, in any case:

```
localStorage["data"] = "hi!"
localStorage.getItem("data")        // -> "hi!"
localStorage["data"]                // -> "hi!"
localStorage.hasOwnProperty["data"] // -> true (exposed property in Chrome)

delete localStorage["data"]
localStorage.getItem("data")        // -> null
localStorage["data"]                // -> undefined
localStorage.hasOwnProperty["data"] // -> false (property is gone)
```

See [Deleting from localStorage: should I use delete or .removeItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906494/deleting-from-localstorage-should-i-use-delete-or-removeitem)

Comment: thank you so much for explain it to me. Ive tried giving it an object since i want it to check if user is logged and redirect to loign page if not. i will try your answer and let you know what happened. thanks a lot

Comment: Hi what if i want to check if the key was set from the login page. ihave this `localStorage['data1b']=JSON.stringify({logedIn:0})` on the login and this`localStorage['data'] = JSON.stringify({folder1: {logedIn: 1}, folder2: {logedIn: 0}, folder3: {logedIn: 1}});` on the index. how do i make something like this using your answer? thansk for further help.